# Switch Firestore ref if document does not exist

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build the following:

When a user request data, if the data does not exist, I want to provide a fallback Document.
I'm using AngularFire2.

Inspired by [the doc here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) I thought I could use first the `.get()` method to check if the document exists then return the AngularFire2 Observable. But this does not work.

Why doesn't this function currently return the request Observable?

```
displayQuestion(questionId: string, lang: string) {

    const cityRef = this.afs.firestore.collection("game").doc(`${questionId}`).collection(`${lang}`).doc('content')

    cityRef.get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          console.log('No such document!');
          return this.afs.doc(`/game/${questionId}/en/content`).valueChanges()
        } else {
          console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
          return this.afs.collection("game").doc(`${questionId}`).collection(`${lang}`).doc('content').valueChanges()
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting document', err);
      })
}
```

Comment: in AngularFire2 way try `cityRef.ref.get()`

Answer (score 0):

if you still have this problem, you can check this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1272) from the angularfire2 library repo.

You can write for example:

```
const myContentDoc = this.afs.doc(`game/${questionID}/${lang}/content`);
```

Then, you can do:

```
myContentDoc.snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).toPromise()
    .then((action: any) => {
        if (!action.payload.exists) {
            return this.afs.doc(`game/${anotherQuestionID}/${lang}/content`).ref.get();
        }
    });
```